# setState update array value using index in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to update array value using index, is below code ok?

```
handleChange = index => e => {
  const { rocket } = this.state // ['tesla', 'apple', 'google']
  rocket[index] = e.target.value
  this.setState({ rocket })
}
```

my jsx

```
<div>{rocket.map((val,i) => <input type="text" onChange={handleChange(i)} value={val} />)}</div>
```

I know it worked, but just to be sure it's ok to mutate the state like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It's not okay to mutate state this way.**

The following line mutates the array in the current state in a way that can lead to bugs in your program particularly with components down the Component tree using that state. 
This is because the state is still the same array.

```
rocket[index] = e.target.value
//console.log(this.state.rocket) and you see that state is updated in place
```

**Always treat state as immutable**

You can remedy this by writing.

```
const newRocket = [
  ...rocket.slice(0, index),
  e.target.value, 
  ...rocket.slice(index + 1)
]
```

This way a new array is created and components in the Component tree can be updated when React does a [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html).

**Note that**
The only way to mutate state should be through calls to `Component.setState`.

Now that you have a new array, you can update the component state like so:

```
this.setState({ rocket: newRocket })
```

Comment: Yes, mapping over the array items creates a new array. However, it means writing code like this: `this.setState({rocket: rocket.map((val, idx) => i === idx ? e.target.value :  val)})`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing existing value, you could use [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

> The **`splice()`** method changes the contents of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

```js
var arr= ['A','B','E','D'];
arr.splice(2,1,'C')
console.log(arr)//The result will be  ['A','B','C','D'];
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

**[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rgwskk)**

---

**CODE SNIPPET**

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'Demo using Array.prototype.slice()',
      rocket: ['tesla', 'apple', 'google'],
      link: 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice'
    };
  }

  handleChange(index, e) {
    const { rocket } = this.state;
    rocket.splice(index, 1, e.target.value)
    this.setState({ rocket: [...rocket] }, () => {
      //call back function of set state you could check here updated state
      console.log(this.state.rocket)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <b><a target="_blank" href={this.state.link}>{this.state.name}</a></b>
        {
          this.state.rocket.map((val, i) =>
            <p key={i}>
              <input type="text" onChange={(e) => { this.handleChange(i, e) }} value={val} />
            </p>)
        }</div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: using map is doable because I can check the index too right?

Comment: The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. that's why is doable.

Answer (score 0):

you can try on this

```
  const onChangeProduct = (e, index) => {
    console.log("Value price " + e);
    const updateItem =  [...imports];
    updateItem[index]["product"] = e;
    setImports(updateItem);

  }



 <Select
         className="w-40"
            showSearch
            placeholder="Select product"
            optionFilterProp="children"      
            value={element.product}
            onChange= {(e) => onChangeProduct(e, index)}
            options={
                items
            }
          />
```